# Parsing a structured file using Tcl and picking some values?

Tags: parsing, tcl

I have got a semi structured text file, from which I want to extract values and save them for later use.
The file has some config data for a simulation environment, the env. is made up of different sub-systems, for one of these sub-systems I want to find the number of them, and their specific type.
This is how the file is structured

```
<Begin_Subsystem_Configuration>
Subsystem_Name:"PLC1_ARR":
Subsystem_Identifier:0x01B1B000:
Subsystem_Type:PLC_BERGHOF:
IP_Address:"10.70.9.11":
Port_Numbers:3500:3500:
Alive_Message_Period:10:
Max_Communication_Latency:5:
Switch_Over_Timeout:15:
Member_Count:6:
Subsystem_Member_1:77:77:       # PS SR1
Subsystem_Member_2:106:106:     # SZ PTHA
Subsystem_Member_3:110:110:     # SZ PTH1
Subsystem_Member_4:310:310:     # SZ YL1
Subsystem_Member_5:311:311:     # SZ DOOR1
Subsystem_Member_6:312:312:     # SZ FIRE1
<End_Subsystem_Configuration>
```

Now I want to know, how often the pattern PLC_BERGHOF Occur in the file, I actually can do that already, but now if it is found I would like to save in some sort of assoc. array the key-value pair of the line before, and the 3 lines after the line in which the patter found.

Later on in my script I would like to be able to access the values like that:
set plc1_IP_Address array['plc1_IP_Address'],
 the exact sysntax of accessing that doesnt really matter, the code has just to go into a Tcl Script

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Tcl 8.5 then I suggest you read the file line by line building up a set of [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm) objects to hold each subsystem as a collection of name:item pairs. You can then create a list of such dicts to represent the whole file or whatever makes sense to you. Then something like:

```
foreach config $list_of_dicts {
    if {[dict get $config Subsystem_Type] eq "PLC_BERGHOF"} {
        puts "[dict get $config IP_Address]\n[dict get $config Port_Numbers]"
    }
}
```

Although from the sound of your description: `grep -A 3 PLC_BERGHOF` would be sufficient.

If not using 8.5 then you don't have `dict` but a list of name item pairs can be managed in much the same way. You just end up using `lsearch` more or converting the list of pairs into an array just to look things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
set fh [open "file.data" r]
array set data []
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    switch -exact -- $line {
        "<Begin_Subsystem_Configuration>" -
        "<End_Subsystem_Configuration>"   {continue}
        default {
            set fields [split $line ":"]
            set values [list]
            foreach value [lrange $fields 1 end-1] {
                if {[string match {"*"} $value]} {
                    lappend values [string range $value 1 end-1]
                } else {
                    lappend values $value 
                }
            }
            set data([lindex $fields 0]) $values
        }
    }
}
close $fh
```

Then you can use

```
if {$data(Subsystem_Type eq "PLC_BERGHOF"} {
    puts "IP address is: $data(IP_Address)"
}
```

I assume your file is actually formatted as following, and you were having trouble getting your question formatted just right:

```
<Begin_Subsystem_Configuration>
Subsystem_Name:"PLC1_ARR":
...
<End_Subsystem_Configuration>
```

Comment: What if we have , muliple IP addresses line. How to grep all IP address. Subsystem_Type:PLC_BERGHOF:
IP_Address:"11.70.9.13":
Port_Numbers:3500:3500:
Alive_Message_Period:10: How to grep "11.70.9.13" and 10.70.9.11.

Comment: Then instead of `set data([lindex $fields 0]) $values` you'd want `lappend data([lindex $fields 0]) $values`

Comment: if we replace this its prints nothing. How to resolve this. please help.

Comment: You need to ask your own question, so other eyes can see it.